# transfering Folder from windows to linux

Tags: ssh

I want to send a folder from my Windows to a Linux virtual machine, using PSCP. I mention again that  I want to transfer a folder which contains nearly 200 files in it.

Answer (score 1):

pscp on Windows much like scp on Linux has an option '-r' to copy entire directories recursively.

From the manual

> 5.2.2.4 -r copies directories recursively
>
> By default, PSCP will only copy files. Any directories you specify to
>   copy will be skipped, as will their contents. The -r option tells PSCP
>   to descend into any directories you specify, and to copy them and
>   their contents. This allows you to use PSCP to transfer whole
>   directory structures between machines.

If you're on a system that doesn't support the -r option (certain compiles of Busybox for instance), the common way would be to create a tarball or zip file of the folder in question.

Comment: As a side note, if you will be copying the same folder regularly (e.g. uploading a Website from your Windows Desktop to your Linux Server) I would suggest using rsync over ssh as on subsequent copies it only transfers files that changed since the last copy and not the entire directory again.